# Can ByteBuddy static references be made persistent?

Tags: byte-buddy

ByteBuddy offers the feature to define a class with a baked in reference to another object (see [the `MethodCall#withReference()` method](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#withReference-java.lang.Object...-)).  That's very nice and convenient.  My question is around the nature of this reference.

I am embarrassed to say this, but I realize I have been working under the assumption that the reference stored in this static field will be persistent.  That is, if I set up ByteBuddy so that it uses predictable class names and then load them later from a different VM, I have been assuming that whatever was passed in a `withReference` call would be…serialized? stored? in some way.  It does not appear that it is.

(I'm guessing (haven't dug into it) that a `LoadedTypeInitializer` is probably invoked, maybe even by reflection, to populate this field with a simple reference to some other bytecode already present in memory, i.e. I'm guessing that the reference is a simple pointer that is left dangling after the VM quits.)

My question is: the ByteBuddy API is vast, so I often find that I'm missing something—*is* there a facility in ByteBuddy that would let me store a reference to another object persistently?  Or would I have to roll it myself using serialization or something similar?

Comment: A loaded type initializer is serializable with the intend for exactly this, that you can serialize it and deserialize and execute it on a different machine. The options are however endless which is why Byte Buddy does not take care of it since there is likely a better option then Java serialization. Advice can store a serializable value as a base64 encoded byte array and deserialize it on read but i recommend against the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ah; I found the [ByteBuddy support for dynamic constants](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.Dynamic.html) which may give me most of what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is whay the JVM sees for itself here and is certainly the best option. Note that this requires Java 11.